# How to stop javascript loop once match is found in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, for-loop

I tried finding some fixes, but don't seem to be finding what I'm looking for. Maybe its my wording.

So I have this form that once it submits with a 5 digit zip code it checks an array for a matching value, once its matches I want it to show a success message and if It doesn't match then return No match, but currently it returns the message as many time as the array has. I'm still fairly new to JavaScript so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
function getZip(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // Gets the value from the text field "zip" on the form.
    var result = ["48650", "48611", "48746", "48614", "48706"];

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        //console.log(result[i]);

        //if (zip.length == 5 && zip == result[i]){
        if (zip == result[i]) {
            console.log(zip + " is = to " + result[i]);
            alert('Match ' + zip);

        } else if (result[i] != zip) {
            alert("No Match1");
            console.log(zip + " is != to " + result[i]);

        } else {
            alert("No Match2");
            console.log(zip + " is != to " + result[i]);
        }
        //return false;
    }
    if (zip === "") { // Checks if the text field "zip" is empty, if so it returns an error message.
        alert('Please enter a zip code!');

    } else if (zip.length > 5) {
        alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

    } else if (zip.length < 5) {
        alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

    } else if (isNaN(zip)) { // Checks if the text field "zip" for alphabetic characters. The "isNaN" function is to determine if a value does not convert to a number, if so it returns an error message.
        alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
    }
}
</script>
```

**Form:**

```
<div class="searchZip">
    <p>Please enter your zip code for availability</p>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
        <button onclick="getZip(event);">Check</button>
    </form>
    <p id="display"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript exiting for loop without returning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471456/javascript-exiting-for-loop-without-returning)

Comment: @Abhitalks which is also a possible duplicate of [How to stop a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830650/how-to-stop-a-for-loop) :)

Comment: Thats not the only issue though, its still retunring only the first result and not getting to the others int eh array to match up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, you could use `break` to exit out of the loop.

I would not use a loop though. Instead, I would use the [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function to determine if there is a match:

```js
function getZip(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // Gets the value from the text field "zip" on the form.
  var result = ["48650", "48611", "48746", "48614", "48706"];

  if (zip === "") { // Checks if the text field "zip" is empty, if so it returns an error message.
    alert('Please enter a zip code!');

  } else if (zip.length > 5) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

  } else if (zip.length < 5) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

  } else if (isNaN(zip)) { // Checks if the text field "zip" for alphabetic characters. The "isNaN" function is to determine if a value does not convert to a number, if so it returns an error message. 
    alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
  } else {
    var match = result.some(function(r) {
      return zip === r;
    });

    if (match) {
      alert('Match ' + match);
    } else {
      alert("No Match");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="searchZip">
  <p>Please enter your zip code for availability</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
    <button onclick="getZip(event);">Check</button>
  </form>
  <p id="display"></p>
</div>
```

*Or, you could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for a simple match like yours.*

Answer (score 5):

Use [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) to break out of loop.

In your case there's no need of `for`, use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if the array contain an element.

You can also use HTML5 `pattern` attribute with regex `[1-9][0-9]{4}`.

```js
var result = ["48650", "48611", "48746", "48614", "48706"],
  display = document.getElementById('display');

function getZip(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value,
    message = '',
    className = 'valid';

  // Remove classes
  display.classList.remove('valid')
  display.classList.remove('invalid');

  // Check if entered valid zipcode
  if (/^[1-9][0-9]{4}$/.test(zip) === false) {
    message = 'Please enter valid 5 digit zip code';
    className = 'invalid';
  } else {
    var index = result.indexOf(zip);

    if (index > -1) {
      message = 'Zip ' + zip + ' found at index ' + index;
    } else {
      message = 'Zip not found in array';
    }
  }

  // Show message
  display.innerHTML = message;
  display.classList.add(className);
}
```

```css
#zip:invalid,
.invalid {
  color: red;
}
.valid {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchZip">
  <p>Please enter your zip code for availability</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{4}">
    <button onclick="getZip(event);">Check</button>
  </form>
  <p id="display"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: So if I put it here, this should work?

} else if (result[i] != zip) {
        alert("No Match1");
        console.log(zip + " is != to " + result[i]);
        break;

Comment: @DallasClymer If you put `break` in the loop, the control will be thrown outside of `for` and the rest of the code will be executed

Comment: While we are at the `pattern` attribute, the `if (zip.length..` could also be replaced by the `required` attribute.

Comment: @Abhitalks In JS? `required` will only check for the any value, here OP want to have a 5-digits, so added it.

Comment: Oh yes @Tushar. My bad, overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

Put `break` in the condition branch body

```js
function getZip(e){
e.preventDefault();
var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // Gets the value from the text field "zip" on the form.
var result = ["48650","48611","48746","48614","48706"];

  for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    //console.log(result[i]);

      //if (zip.length == 5 && zip == result[i]){
        if (zip == result[i]){
          console.log(zip + " is = to " + result[i]);
          alert('Match ' + zip);
          break;

        } else if (result[i] != zip) {
        alert("No Match1");
        console.log(zip + " is != to " + result[i]);
          break;

        } else {
        alert("No Match2");
        console.log(zip + " is != to " + result[i]);
          break;
      }
        //return false;
  }
  if (zip === "") { // Checks if the text field "zip" is empty, if so it returns an error message.
    alert('Please enter a zip code!');

  } else if (zip.length > 5) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

  } else if (zip.length < 5) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

  } else if (isNaN(zip))  { // Checks if the text field "zip" for alphabetic characters. The "isNaN" function is to determine if a value does not convert to a number, if so it returns an error message. 
    alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="searchZip">
  <p>Please enter your zip code for availability</p>
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
           <button onclick="getZip(event);">Check</button>
     </form>
     <p id="display"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The breaks only work to show the first match in the array, and the rest show as false becasue it's not looping through the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm can be even easier

```js
function getZip(e){
e.preventDefault();
var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // Gets the value from the text field "zip" on the form.
var result = ["48650","48611","48746","48614","48706"];

        if (result.indexOf(zip) === -1){
          alert("No Match1");
        } else {
          alert('Match ' + zip);
        }
   
  if (zip === "") { // Checks if the text field "zip" is empty, if so it returns an error message.
    alert('Please enter a zip code!');

  } else if (zip.length > 5) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

  } else if (zip.length < 5) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit numeric zip code.");

  } else if (isNaN(zip))  { // Checks if the text field "zip" for alphabetic characters. The "isNaN" function is to determine if a value does not convert to a number, if so it returns an error message. 
    alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="searchZip">
  <p>Please enter your zip code for availability</p>
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
           <button onclick="getZip(event);">Check</button>
     </form>
     <p id="display"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This did simply it, may I ask what the  if (result.indexOf(zip) === -1){ means?

Comment: `indexOf` returns index of the value in the array. It returns -1, if the value is not found.