# How to stop lodash.js _.each loop?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this rows code:

```
_.each($scope.inspectionReviews, function (value, key) {
    alert("status=" + value.IsNormal + "   " + "name=" + value.InspectionItemName);
    if (!value.IsNormal) {
        $scope.status = false;
        return;
    }
    $scope.status = true;
})
```

At some point I want to stop looping but it seems that return not working.

How can I stop the loop?

Comment: Did you try `return false` ?

Comment: Try to [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830650/how-to-stop-a-for-loop)

Comment: @GuiImamura - this is not a regular `for` loop.  This is a lodash or underscore `.each()` loop.  You can't use `break` for that.

Comment: You've tagged this `lodash` and `underscore.js` - which is it?

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for pointing it out. I'm studying lodash right now to see how it works, I'll see underscore right after.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
return false;
```

Use this in a lodash `each` to break.

EDIT: I have seen the title changed to underscore. Is it underscore or lodash? As I pointed out above you can break an `each` in lodash but underscore I believe emulates `forEach` which natively doesn't provide that.

Comment: Any advantage of `return false;` over `return` ? Or just for readability ?

Comment: @RayonDabre If its lodash the advantage is breaking the loop. Just using return will not break out of the loop, you must return false to achieve that.

Comment: @RayonDabre `return` with no parameter is equivalent to `return undefined`, which is the same as falling off the end of the function without using a `return` statement.

Comment: @Barmar, So only `return` will return the control flow and break the iterations right ?

Comment: @RayonDabre No, return like he said is just returning undefined, only returning false will break the loop and stop any subsequent iterations.

Comment: @RayonDabre Normally the iteration function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `undefined`. If returning undefined stopped the iteration, you would never get more than one iteration. That's why it requires an explicit `return false` as the flag to tell it to break.

Comment: return; is like continue in this case.

Comment: what happen if you return **true** instead?

Comment: @s1moner3d the each loop would continue until you return false or it completes.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace thank u! That's for covering every case **undefined|true|false**

Comment: FYI about the Underscore/LoDash name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898916/493807 -- In short, LoDash can be used as a drop-in replacement for Underscore.

Answer (score 24):

- **return false** => it has exactly the same effect as using `break;`
- **return** => this is the same as using `continue;`

Comment: It would be better if you explain why your answer would be helpful.

Comment: it is better because flow control. the answer shows the difference between not returning anything (which would cause the loop to skip to the next element) or returning false (which would cause the loop to stop alltogether)

I learned something today. Thanks @jack wu

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test to see if a certain condition is true for any of the collection's members, use Underscore's [some](http://underscorejs.org/#some) (aliased as [any](http://underscorejs.org/#some)) instead of `each`.

```
var hasAtLeastOneFalseStatus = _.any($scope.inspectionReviews, function (value, key) {
    return !value.IsNormal;
})

$scope.status = hasAtLeastOneFalseStatus ? false: true;
```