# Break for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to break my for loop that I have 10 numbers in a line.

```
for(var i = 100; i <=300; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a JavaScript for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830650/how-to-stop-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: Have you investigated the `break` statement?

Comment: Hey richard flagged a duplicate to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830650/how-to-stop-a-javascript-for-loop

Comment: "that I have 10 numbers in a line" - what does that mean

Comment: My loop starts from 100, when it gets to 110, it breaks and skip a line. And continue reading when it reaches 120, skips a line. @Zeratul

Comment: *breaking a loop* and *linebreak* are two very different things.

Comment: Possible dumplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564818/how-to-break-nested-loops-in-javascript/1564838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your statement, "My loop starts from 100, when it gets to 110, it breaks and skip a line. And continue reading when it reaches 120, skips a line:

```
        for(let i = 100; i <=300; i++){                         
            if(i % 10 == 0) {               
                continue;
            }           
            console.log(i);
        }
```

A `break` will exit the loop completely, a `continue` will skip to the next iteration.  This skips every loop iteration that's divisible by 10.

Comment: The second one was more helpful.

Comment: please mark as the answer if it correctly answers your question

Answer (score 1):

I guess by "that I have 10 numbers in a line." you mean to break the line after 10 printed numbers. It seems not to be possible to log to the console without a linebreak, so you have to concatenate the output until 10 outputs are concatenated.

```
var line = '';              // initialize line variable
for(var i = 100; i <=300; i++) {
    line += i               // append current value to the line without printing it
    if ((i%10) === 0) {       // check, if the current iteration is dividable by 10
        console.log(line);    // output the collected output
        line = ''             // reset the line var
    }
}
if (line !== '') console.log(line);    // if the total count was not dividable
                                       // by 10, output the left over
```

Comment: Hi. Your answer didn’t really answer my question as the question is not straightforward. But I was wondering if you could comment this code. I’d like to investigate it. Thanks.

Comment: Added some comments :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I’m practicing on something and I used this code to get a line of numbers where when I input a given integer, I get steps of that number counting downward like 1, next step 2, next step 3, and so on. I want to know if you can give a code where I can get the same steps of downward numbers, but backwards. I.e 1, next step 2 backward of 1 not forward. I don’t know if you understand.

Answer (score -1):

you can use if condition inside your for loop lets say if you want to break the loop after 10 numbers printed just add this line in your for loop

```
if(i==10)
{
   break;
}
```

The break condition will bring you out of the for loop.