# stop executing loop on certain condition and wait for click, then continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, infinite-loop

I need infinite loop(or other alternative) that increase my variable, and when this variable have certain value (100 or more) execution of this loop stop and wait for user click. After that, loop continues.

something like this:

```
var speed = 0;

for(i=0; i>=0; i++){
    speed += 13;
    if(speed >= 100){
        // wait for this click
        $(“.el”).click(()=> {
            // some code
            speed = 0;
        });
    }
    //then continue loop with - speed = 0
}
```

written on javascript

Maybe can achieved with promises, await or something like that, but I can’t. I appreciate if anyone help me, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a JavaScript for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830650/how-to-stop-a-javascript-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) seems like the right guy for the job.
To *off* a click use jQuery's `.off()`Method. Also, the `.one()` method to attach a callback only *once*:

```js
const $btn = $("#btn");
const $log = $("#log");
let speed = 0;
let tO = null;

function clickHandle( evt ) {
  console.log("CLICKED");   // Do something here
  // ....
  $btn.off("click", clickHandle); // Prevent further clicks
  loop(); // restart the loop!
}

function loop() {
  if (speed >= 100) {
    clearTimeout(tO);
    $btn.one("click", clickHandle); // Allow one click only
    speed = 0; // Reset speed to 0
    return; // Exit here, we're at >=100
  }
  
  speed += 13;
  $log.text(speed);
  tO = setTimeout(loop, 150); // Do +13 every 150ms
}

// init:
loop();
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Restart</button>
<div id="log"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used JQuery but this is the code done recursively.

```js
let speed = 0;

document.querySelector(".el").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // some code
  speed = 0;

  // this restarts the loop
  loop()
}, false)


function loop() {
  speed += 13;
  if (speed < 100) {
    loop();
  }
}
// to start the loop
loop();
```

```html
<button class="el">Click ME</button>
```