# How can I refactor this to improve performance

Tags: javascript

I have code as below. Empty array is pushed when there is not data. Which I think is inefficient and not clean.

The reason for doing this is we need statusMapped to be pushed inside arrayOfStatusMapped in proper index order -  So that while I need to display data, I can loop over and display data for exact index position. I need to know which index was empty, which index position had data.

Is there a better way of rewriting this code, that could improve performance. Thank you.

```
var statusMapped = [];  
var arrayOfStatusMapped = [];

//for (i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) 
data.forEach((val, i) => {

// length could be in 100 thousands...
{
    if (data[i].status) 
    { 
       // only few passes this condition // lets assume 100.
        var statusValue = value;
        var Key = getKeyByValue(statusList, statusValue ); // Func that returns 'key' of the value passed.
        statusMapped .push(Key);
        arrayOfStatusMapped .push(statusMapped); // only 100 non-empty array gets pushed
    }                                  
    else 
    {  
        // So, anything that does not satisfy the condition in 'if', will have empty array pushed as below.
        arrayOfStatusMapped .push([]); // remaining 99,900 arrays are empty                    
    }
})
```

We use the result of above code to display data:

```
 arrayOfStatusMapped[index].forEach((status, i) => {                        
           ${arrayOfStatusMapped[index][i] 
 }
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)? [How to stop a JavaScript for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9830650)

Comment: I think you're focusing on the wrong efficiency. Why do you need a dataset containing _"100 thousands"_ records that you're trying to display? There has to be a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Empty array"? Is that an array with array entries that are without valid data? Or, is the array literally empty without any elements - zero entries?

Comment: I have a chart, in which my x-axis displays time (I get hundreds of thousands of data for time). Status might or might not get generated for every time that is generated. But I need to show the status (at the exact time it was generated) whenever it was generated.

Comment: Yes it is an empty array without any elements. Reason is to know at which index the status was generated. So that I can plot on the chart.

Comment: Based on a quick check it seems native Array methods like "filter" and "forEach" are +10 times faster than a standard for loop.

Comment: @yogi thank you, that was helpful. But dint give drastic improvement.  I would appreciate if anything else can be changed to improve performance.

Comment: What are you using to display the data? Why do you believe its inefficient (i.e., does the graph library take too long to generate?)? Is there a more fuller code snippet you have?

Comment: Yes, rite now I have only minimal data, which itself takes 3 to 4 seconds to generate graph. When I have more data, it would take more time. I use Highchart. I will share fuller code snippet soon. Thank you.